# Erro ao fazer GET de url de imagem no Json Android

Tags: java, android, json

Eu tenho o seguinte código:

```
    private class DownloadJsonAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {...}

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        p = new ControllerPosts();
        arrayList = new ArrayList<>();

        // Creating service handler class instance
        cx =  new Conexao();
        String jsonStr = cx.get(url);

        Log.d("Resposta: ", "> " + jsonStr);

        if (jsonStr != null) {

            try {
                // De-serialize the JSON
                JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
                // Getting JSON Array node
                 posts = jsonObj.getJSONArray(TAG_TIPO);

                // looping through All Contacts
                for (int i = 0; i < posts.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = posts.getJSONObject(i);

                    p.setId(Integer.parseInt(c.getString(TAG_ID)));
                    p.setTitulo(c.getString(TAG_TITULO));
                    p.setData(c.getString(TAG_DATA));
                    p.setConteudo(c.getString(TAG_CONTEUDO));
                   // p.setImagem(c.getString(TAG_IMAGEM));

                    // Aqui onde está gerando o erro
                    JSONObject img = c.getJSONObject(TAG_IMAGEM);
                 //   JSONObject thumb = img.getJSONObject("thumbnail");
                    p.setImagem(c.getString(img.getString(TAG_URL_IMAGEM)));

                    // tmp hash map for single contact
                    HashMap<String, String> post= new HashMap<>();

                    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                    post.put(TAG_ID, String.valueOf(p.getId()));
                    post.put(TAG_TITULO, p.getTitulo());
                    post.put(TAG_DATA, p.getData());
                    post.put(TAG_CONTEUDO, p.getConteudo());
                    post.put(TAG_URL_IMAGEM, p.getImagem());

                    // adding post to post list
                    arrayList.add(post);

                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.e("tag", "Erro ao processar o JSON", e);
            }

        } else {
            Log.e("Get: ", "Não foi possível obter quaisquer dados do url");
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Ele funcionará corretamente, até eu precisar fazer um get de imagem, ele mostra a mensagem no debug:

Value http://localhost/teste/imagem.png at thumbnail of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Alguém consegue me dar uma luz onde estou errando?

Obrigado

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema é que você está passando uma URL e tentando convertê-la para um objeto JSON. A `String` que você deve passar para o `getJSONObject` deve estar no formato JSON. Para que a URL possa ser convertida num objeto JSON válido, ela deveria estar no seguinte formato, por exemplo:

```
{
  "url": "http://localhost/teste/imagem.png"
}
```

Nesse formato você vai conseguir gerar um objeto que mapeia a url ao seu valor.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela resposta, meu json está assim:

 "thumbnail":{"url":"http:\/\/localhost\/wp-content\/uploads\/2016\/09\/bootstrap-150x150.png","width":150,"height":150},

Eu preciso pegar a url dele, qual a melhor forma de eu fazer isso usando o meu código parse?

Comment: Chamando o c.getJSONObject. Para isso, você coloca a string completa do teu JSON como parâmetro ("\"thumbnail\" ... "). Eu gosto de usar o ObjectMapper (com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper) porque quando ele converte você pode passar um objeto para encapsular tudo, aí ele sai prontinho. Depois dá uma olhada, se você tiver interesse.

Comment: Então, não conhecia o ObjectMapper, vou dar uma estudada nele sim, obrigado. No meu código eu estou tentando fazer isso que disse: 
                    
                        JSONObject img = c.getJSONObject("thumbnail");
                        p.setImagem(img.getString("url"));
Que esta dando o erro..rs

Comment: É porque você está passando "thumbnail" como parâmetro. Você precisar passar a string json completa.

Comment: Entendi, você tem razão! obrigado pela ajuda